# Rotate a polygon

Tags: c#, timer, rotation, polygon, points

I've been searching around this webpage the way I can rotate a Polygon but I might be losing something or just don't getting it.

My drawing is a star but it's just a bunch of triangules so if I can rotate correctly one of them I can make the others rotate correctly too.
So, heres the code for one triangle

```
Point[] pico1 = new Point[3];
            pico1[0] = new Point(220, 240);   //Origin         
            pico1[1] = new Point(220, 40);
            pico1[2] = new Point(160, 140);
g.FillPolygon(Rojo2, pico2);
```

g is a global Graphics variable that equals e.Graphics of the paint event on a PictureBox.

Then I have a timer and I want that every tick the polygon rotates. I tried on 90° each tick but my triangle just get deformed.
So I really don't have any idea how to get new coords for that point. Teacher said that I can do something like this:

```
Point[] pico1 = new Point[3];
                pico1[0] = new Point(220, 240);   //Origin         
                pico1[1] = new Point(220+px, 40+py);
                pico1[2] = new Point(160+px, 140+py);
    g.FillPolygon(Rojo1, pico1);
```

px and py are global variables that have an initial value of 0. I guess that this two help me to get the new point but I'm really lost.

Is there any easier way to rotate that triangle around (220, 240)? Or how can I do it with px and py? I really have no idea what to do. I found some posts here that use sin and cos but when I try to use it in my code the polygon still deforms.

Comment: Using `Sin` and `Cos` should be how you handle such transformation. This is a geometric problem after all. If there is any deformation, is likely caused by wrong geometrical formula you use. You can show how you use the `Sin` and `Cos` and how it has wronged you (show the deformation).

Comment: You have two options: 1) calculate with Math.Sin etc.. 2) rotate the Graphics object by a angle. The first is pure math, not hard, but using a few trigonometric formulas or maby setting up a matrix. The latter is as simple as doing a  Graphics.RotateTransform (after doing a TranslateTransform to move the origin to the center of the rotation). It really depends what you are supposed to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

The best course really depends on what you are supposed to do:

- Since you are in class, chances are that you are supposed to find an analytical solution that will involve calculating the rotated positions of all points.
- In real life, or if the theacher didn't explictily demand a mathematical solution, there is an old rule:

> Always use the system sort

This refers to the question whether to write a *bubble sort* or a *quicksort* or some other sort routine. And the **best** solution is always to use the built-in sort, as it will be fast and reliable..

In this case the best and most efficient solution is to use the built-in rotation ability of GDI+, if that's what you are using. Inserting these two lines will do the job:

```
g.TranslateTransform(220, 240);
g.RotateTransform(angle);
g.FillPolygon(Rojo2, pico1);
```

You will need two class level variables to calculate the angle and a `Timer.Tick` to do the rotation in an animation:

```
float angularSpeed = 1.5f;
float angle = 0f;

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    angle = (angle + angularSpeed) % 360; 
    yourPictureBox.Invalidate(); 
}
```

I used the coordinates you have named to be the origin. They need to be the same for all your shapes or else they will drift apart. You can find the center of a polygon by adding it to a `GraphicsPath` and calculating the center of the bounding rectangle: `gp.GetBounds()`..

Btw: I hope you are not really **caching** the `Graphics` object, as this is a bad idea!! Instead always use the one from the `Paint` event, passing it on from the event, but **not holding on to it**, as it needs to be always current!

If you need to go for calculating you will have to do some math. Look at the answers in the sidebar to the right; they are mostly in java, but the calculations are basically the same..

The code you quoted as your teacher's hint doesn't make an sense to me; the amount of movement will depend on the relative position of each point to the origin. So points at the opposite side will move in the opposite direction.. You probably got him wrong.